# How to change foreground color according to background color

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using this color palette;
[image]

This is what final graph looks like:
[image]

How do I adjust foreground color according to background color? My first intuition was to swap the color. For instance if it is the last color then swap it with the minimum color. But that blurs out the middle ones.

```
p = myset.index(p0[i])
print(str(set_length )+'-'+ str(p))
print(set_length - p-1)
c = colors[set_length - p-1]

cv2.putText(img, TEXT, text_origin, TEXT_FACE, TEXT_SCALE, (c[2],c[1],c[0]))
```

I take index of number in a list ordered in ascending order. Then color is get according to that index. Length of list is subtracted from this color.

Comment: Check the first answer here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/given-a-rgb-color-x-how-to-find-the-most-contrasting-color-y

Comment: @Błotosmętek is there any way to summarize it and put it in more understandable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# First, store your palette:
pal = sns.color_palette("Or_Rd", 10)
# this function creates a contrasting color for given (r, g, b)
def contrast(x):
    return tuple( 0 if c > 0.5 else 1 for c in x )
# so to create a list of colors contrasting with your palette:
contrasting_colors = [ contrast(c) for c in pal ]
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-16-a555442428d9>", line 473
    return tuple( c > 0.5 ? 0 : 1 for c in x )
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It says invalid syntax at ?

Comment: Sorry, damn Perl habits. Corrected.